# How do I find P(X > x + y | X > x), y > 0 when X is an exponential RV

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, exponential-distribution

I'm struggling to see how I would manipulate the PDF so that I could find the conditional probability?

X is an exponential RV with $\lambda>0$ and the pdf=$\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$

Comment: $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$. In this case, when the event $X>x+y$ occurs, the event $X>x$ always occurs, so $A\cap B=A$.

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$
\mathbb{P}[X > x+y | X>x]
 = \frac{\mathbb{P}[X > x+y, X>x]}{\mathbb{P}[X>x]}
 = \frac{\mathbb{P}[X > x+y]}{\mathbb{P}[X>x]}
 = \frac{1-F(x+y)}{1-F(x)}.
$$
where $F$ is the cdf of the r.v. in question. Can you compute $F$ from your pdf and simplify the resulting expression? It looks quite nice in the end...